# JavaFX - Check if a control is the default focused control

Tags: javafx, user-controls, focus

How do I check if a button is the default focused control?

My attempt ...

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
    if(fxBtn.isFocused() == true)
    {
        fxLbl.setText("Some string here");
    }
}
```

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, with parent being the container of your nodes:

```
    for( Node node: parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
        if( node.isVisible() && !node.isDisabled() && node.isFocusTraversable())
            return node;
    }
    return null;
```

It gives you the node with the default focus, i. e. the one Node that receives the focus first.

Your "attempt" only gives you the information whether a node has the focus or not.

Just in case you didn't express yourself correctly, if you're searching for making a Button the default button you can use [setDefaultButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#setDefaultButton-boolean-), and [isDefaultButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#isDefaultButton--) for checking if a Button is the default button.